# Animate Parts Of UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, animation

I would like to create an expandable table view cell where on click of a specific portion of the cell I would like to animate and expand the cell.

I am able to expand and collapse on tap with default animation which basically fades the view changes. But I would like to animate the rotation on the indicator image and expand the cell.

**Here is how it is being animated currently.**

[image: Current Animation Behaviour]

**Here is my code for the table view**

```
class ExpandableTableView: UITableView {
    
    var status:[Bool] = [Bool].init(repeating: false, count: 10)
 
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        self.registerCell()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.registerCell()
    }
    
    func registerCell() {
        self.register(UINib(nibName: "DemoTableViewCell", bundle: .main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell")
        self.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ExpandableTableView: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return status.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell") as? DemoTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.setHeader("Header \(indexPath.row) : Status \(self.status[indexPath.row])")
        cell.setStatus(isExpanded: self.status[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

extension ExpandableTableView: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.status[indexPath.row] = !self.status[indexPath.row]
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

**Here is the code for UITableViewCell**

```
class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private var lblHeader:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgIndicator: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var containerStackView:UIStackView!
  
    func setHeader(_ header:String) {
        self.lblHeader.text = header
    }
    
    func setStatus(isExpanded:Bool) {
        self.containerStackView.isHidden = !isExpanded
        if (isExpanded){
            self.imgIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/2)
        }else {
            self.imgIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        }
        self.containerStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Code : [Here is the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i-STKVzebhBIcnL59pcPn3sIbmyQ2kUz/view?usp=sharing) for quick checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure if you tried to put your transformation code into an animation block.

This usually does it for me.

For example:

```
// Set the duration you wish
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.imgIndicator.transform =
        CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
})
```

Gives:

[image: UIImageView UIView Rotate Animation 90 180 360 degrees Core animation]

---

**Update 1 with UITableView Cell Example using autolayout**

Custom tableview cell

```
fileprivate class CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var imgIndicator: UIImageView!
    
    static let tableViewCellIdentifier = "cell"
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,
                  reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style,
                   reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        configureIndicator()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configureIndicator()
    {
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(textStyle: .largeTitle)
        
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right.circle",
                            withConfiguration: config)
        
        imgIndicator = UIImageView(image: image)
        
        imgIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(imgIndicator)
        
        // auto-layout
        imgIndicator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
            .isActive = true
        imgIndicator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor)
            .isActive = true
        imgIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgIndicator.heightAnchor,
                                            multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        imgIndicator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
            .isActive = true
    }
    
    // Simplified just to do the animation
    // Customize with your logic
    func setStatus(isExpanded: Bool)
    {
        if isExpanded
        {
            imgIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
        }
    }
}
```

Basic View controller configuration

```
class TableViewAnimationVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // This is just view set up, you can ignore this
        title = "Animation rotation"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    private func configureTableView()
    {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.tableViewCellIdentifier)
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // remove additional rows
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        // Auto layout
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
            .isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
            .isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
            .isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
            .isActive = true
    }
}
```

Tableview datasource

```
extension TableViewAnimationVC: UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // random number
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.tableViewCellIdentifier)
            as! CustomCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Tap to rotate"
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

TableView delegate

```
extension TableViewAnimationVC: UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Retrieved the actual cell that was tapped
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        // Perform animation in block
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            cell.setStatus(isExpanded: true)
        } completion: { (success) in
            if success
            {
                // do your processing after the animation has completed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Final result:

[image: Animate UIView in TableView Cell UITableView UITableViewCell rotate UIImageView swift iOS]

**Update 2 with OPs code example**

The issue seems to be with using the same animation block used to reload the table view and perform other UIView animations.

The option I see is to separate both these animations.

One option would be to finish the rotation animation and then reload your tableview row for the expand - you can experiment with this.

I will show you the second option which seemed to be a better user experience. At a high level:

1. Figure out which cell should currently be animated
2. Reload the table view row with animation
3. In a seperate UIView animation block, perform your other animations

Here are the changes I made to achieve the above:

First, in your cell class

```
class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private var lblHeader:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgIndicator: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var containerStackView:UIStackView!
  
    // No change
    func setHeader(_ header:String) {
        self.lblHeader.text = header
    }
    
    // Contract / expand the table view cell only
    func setStatus(isExpanded:Bool) {
        self.containerStackView.isHidden = !isExpanded
        self.containerStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    // Animate the indicator separately
    func animateIndicator()
    {
        var endAngle: CGFloat = .pi/2.0
        var startAngle = CGFloat.zero
        
        if self.containerStackView.isHidden
        {
            startAngle = .pi/2
            endAngle = .zero
        }
        
        imgIndicator.transform
            = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: startAngle)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            self?.imgIndicator.transform
                = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: endAngle)
        }
        completion: { (success) in
            // do anything
        }
    }
}
```

In `ExpandableTableView` I made a few changes:

```
// Unchanged, done by you
var status:[Bool] = [Bool].init(repeating: false, count: 10)

// Stores the current cell's index path which should be animated
// This is for my convenience as I couldn't grasp your complete logic
// you can edit based on your logic
var shouldAnimate: [IndexPath] = []
```

Changes in UITableViewDelegate

```
extension ExpandableTableView: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.status[indexPath.row] = !self.status[indexPath.row]
        
        // Added by me to keep track of which cell to animate
        shouldAnimate.append(indexPath)
        
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        
    }
    
    // Perform your UIView animations in here
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
                   forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let cell = cell as? DemoTableViewCell,
           shouldAnimate.firstIndex(of: indexPath) != nil
        {
            cell.animateIndicator()
        }
    }
    
    // Unchanged
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

The results is close to what I believe you wish achieve:

[image: Animate UIImageView inside UITableView Cell UIView animations iOS Swift Core Animation]

Play around with the timings to try to get the expand and the rotation animation to sync better.

Comment: Have you tried this in UITableViewCell?

Comment: @MalavSoni - yes I did. Updated with an example for you.

Comment: This doesn't work with expandable cells. I have attached my source code with the question. Have a look.

Comment: @MalavSoni - see the last update please